# Using fmap with Parallel.Strategies gives NFData error

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm having some trouble with the `NFData` class in `Control.DeepSeq`. I'd like my type to implement its Functor `fmap` in parallel using the `Control.Parallel.Strategies` module. For example, in the following code, I get an error starting "Could not deduce (NFData b)...". If I use `rseq` instead of `rdeepseq` there is no problem, however I would like to experiment with `rdeepseq`. I have GHC 6.12.3 running under Ubuntu 11.04.

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.DeepSeq

data Foo a = Foo Int [a]
  deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Functor Foo where
  fmap f (Foo i xs) = Foo i (map f xs `using` parList rdeepseq)
```

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, that's not possible.  If you look at your `fmap` you can see that it uses `rdeepseq` which needs the type `a` in the list inside `Foo` to be in class `NFData`.  But there is simply nowhere to attach this constraint, because that type variable is not mentioned anywhere in the instance declaration.

There are various workarounds using non-standard versions of `Functor`, but none of them are pleasant.

Have a look at [Haskell Type Constraints Unleashed](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.1161&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a suggested solution.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you can't do this is basically the same reason why you can't define an instance of `Monad` for `Data.Set`.

Consider the definition of the `Functor` class:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

The functor class requires parametricity over all types `b` while the use of `rdeepseq` in your code is trying to restrict it to `NFData b => b`.

A workaround is to separate out the evaluation from `fmap`, for example by defining an `NFData` instance for `Foo`:

```
instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (Foo i xs) = Foo i (map f xs)

instance NFData a => NFData (Foo a) where
    rnf (Foo i xs) = i `seq` (xs `using` parList rdeepseq) `seq` ()
```

Comment: Great! Do you know why the following doesn't then give `undefined`? `fmap (+1) (Foo 0 [1,2,undefined]) \`deepseq\` 3`

Comment: @user643722: I'm not intimate with `Control.Parallel.Strategies` yet, but it seems like `parList` does not trigger evaluation of the elements when only the outermost `(:)` is evaluated (with `seq` in this example). Changing the second `seq` to `deepseq` gives `undefined` as expected.